# Notification intent flag

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app having two activities, In Activity A has one button and Activity B has audio player with notification content and HOME option menu.

1. Launch Activity A. Click button -> start activity B
2. In Activity B – starting player with notification.
3. Click device back button
4. Activity B destroys and click device back button
5. Activity A destroy
6. Click on notification -> go to Activity B
7. In Activity B Click HOME option menu -> start activity A
8. Click button – NOT WORKING

Any idea?

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ActivityB);
    i.putExtra("NotifID", NOTIFICATION_ID);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);  

    pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext() , 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
    contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.my_notification);


         bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageNotify, bitmap); 
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.titleNotify, text);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textSong, singer);   
    mNotification.contentView = contentView;
    mNotification.contentIntent = pi;
    mNotification.tickerText = text;
    mNotification.icon = R.drawable.icon;

    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

**Activity A,**

```
            playButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.nowplaying));
            playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("isFromList", false);
startActivity(intent);  
        }
    });
```

**In Acitvity B,**

```
      @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        startActivity(myIntent); 
        break;
```

And for notification as mention above.

**manifest**

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.android.ActivityA"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

       <activity
        android:name="com.android.ActivityB"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Are there any errors in the logcat? How does ActivityB start ActivityA when user selects "HOME option menu"?

Comment: no,there is no error in the logcat. while onclick, not starting the activity B. I have created option menu in activity B.

Comment: Please post the code that executes when the user selects HOME option menu in Activity B

Comment: i updated my post, please check.

Comment: Post also your manifest entry for both activityA and activityB

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when user selects "HOME menu option" from ActivityB to start ActivityA you want to go "back to ActivityA". In this case you need to add a call to `finish()` in `onOptionsItemSelected()` after you start ActivityA.

I've asked you to post your manifest entries to ActivityA and ActivityB, this might shed more light on the problem.

Comment: Looked at your manifest. I see no reason why ActivityA should not run. Can you check the logcat (not for errors, but for all messages indicating that the activity was started or not and post the relevant logcat entries.